# Trying to convert my Azure.Storage.Blobs upload code to the new nuget 12.10 and just cannot figure it out. It seemed much simplier in 12.8

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm trying to update my upload and delete code for Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.10 version and just not having any luck.  This is how I used to do it in 12.8:

'''
var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

```
                var fullUri = new UriBuilder()
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = "MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net",
                    Path = $"myimages/{App.User.EmailAddress}/{name}.jpg",
                    Query = subToken
                };

                var blobClient = new BlobClient(fullUri.Uri);

                try
                {
                    using var myStream = File.OpenRead(file.Path);

                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(myStream);

                    myStream.Close();
```

'''

All the examples on github are using the default storage connections string and not a SaS token.  I have a serverless function that gets me a SaS token and I already have the container created.  I just need a simple sample that uses a pre-existing SaS token and container.  Any ideas would be appreciated very much.

John

EDIT:  This is this 12.10 code I have been trying but it doesn't seem to like the URI.

'''

var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

```
                     var blobUri = new BlobUriBuilder(new Uri(
                         $"https://myAccount.blob.core.windows.net/blobcontainer/{App.User.EmailAddress}/{name}.jpg?{subToken}"));

                     var completeUri = blobUri.ToUri();
                     var blobClientNew = new BlobClient(completeUri, null);

                     using var myStream3 = File.OpenRead(file.Path);

                     await blobClientNew.UploadAsync(myStream3);

                     myStream3.Close();
```

'''

Comment: FYI - remove SAS tags as it's not applicable.

Comment: How does your `fullUri.Uri` looks like?

Comment: The code in the post is from 12.8 version not 12.10 but the URI for 12.8 is built like this: ' var fullUri = new UriBuilder()
                {
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Host = "MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net",
                    Path = $"myimages/{App.User.EmailAddress}/{name}.jpg",
                    Query = subToken
                }; ' @GauravMantri

Comment: Please check this might be helpful for you : https://gist.github.com/dazfuller/9b5ea145525879fb5114bd78b53e9ee5#file-azureblobdownload-cs

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT that seems from a very old Azure.Storage SDK version.  I need ideas from the new 12.10 SDK.  But thank you very much for the insight!